# Error SMTP: No se pudo conectar al servidor SMTP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

No puedo enviar correos desde mi aplicación, esto esta con la librería phpMailer, al enviar correos me muestra el mensaje de Error SMTP: No se pudo conectar al servidor SMTP.

Ingreso todos los parámetros del servidor que es el de smtp.gmail.com, usuario, contraseña pero no me permite el envío de correos.

```
                                   para verificar la configuracion SMTP



                                   Test generado por : '.$_SESSION["NOMBREFUNCIONARIO"];


            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = $Debug;
            $mail->SetLanguage('es');
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            $mail->SMTPAuth         = $SMTPAuth;
            $mail->Port             = $Port;

            switch ($SMTPSecure)
            {
                case 'SSL':
                {
                    $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl';
                }
                case 'TLS':
                {
                    $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';
                }
            }

            $mail->Host             = $Host;
            $mail->Username         = $Username;
            $mail->Password         = $Password;
            $mail->From             = $From;
            $mail->FromName         = $FromName;
            $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = $correo_personal;
            $mail->Subject          = $Subject;
            $mail->AltBody          = 'Para poder ver este mensaje utilize un cliente de correo compatible con contenido HTML!';

            $mail->AddAddress('sistemas@plataforma.com.co');
            $mail->AddAddress($CORRALO);

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
              $ale = '


Error enviando e-mail
'.$mail->ErrorInfo.'

';
              echo $ale;
            } else {
              $ale = '


e-mail enviado Correctamente!

Esta Configuracion es valida.

';
              echo $ale;
            }
        }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            echo $e->errorMessage();
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }else{
?>
    
        Por favor escriba una direccion de correo valida para realizar la prueba de envio de e-mail

        

        asiste@server$\ 
    
    
    


    
    
    document.getElementById('CORRALO_SMTP').focus();

    function validar(e) {
      tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if (tecla==13) enviar();
    }

    function enviar(){

        var VARGET = 'CORREO=';
        VARGET += '&SERVIDOR=';
        VARGET += '&USUARIO=';
        VARGET += '&PASSWORD=';
        VARGET += '&SEGURIDAD=';
        VARGET += '&PUERTO=';
        VARGET += '&AUTENTICACION=';
        VARGET += '&CORRALO='+document.getElementById('CORRALO_SMTP').value;

        FAjax('test_smtp.php','RECIBE_TEST_SMTP',VARGET,'post','loading3');
        document.getElementById('CORRALO2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('CORRALO_SMTP').value;
        document.getElementById('CORRALO_SMTP').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras el codigo que estas utilizando, para que sea mas facil ayudarte con tu problema

Comment: Hola Edwin, ya fue agregado el código que es el que se envía para la prueba de correo de la librería phpmailer es  el archivo smtp.php

Comment: Te recomiendo que primariamente utilizar este enlace: [te permite probar que la conexión es correcta mediante los parámetros](https://www.smtper.net). Normalmente para gmail es TLS explícito por el puerto 587.

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta de php mailer desde la configuracion, el codigo, lo visual y las configuraciones si vas a usar un mail de gmail, espero te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214518/3092

Answer (score 1):

Hola te recomiendo igual ser mas especifico con el tipo de error que te da al intentar enviar el correo .

Bien te dejo un ejemplo de como enviar correos  usando **PHPMailer y smtp gmail.com**

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;// TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username ='alguien@gmail.com'; //Email para enviar
$mail->Password = '2132'; //Su password
//Agregar destinatario
$mail->setFrom('user@mail.com', 'Botxtrem Solutions');
$mail->AddAddress('algien@gmail.com');//A quien mandar email
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 


    //Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'PRUEBA 6';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Error al enviar email';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Mail enviado correctamente';
}
```

Saludes