# Consulta sobre PHPMAILER

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, php5, phpmailer

Quería saber si el armado del PHP que estoy haciendo para el envió en un formulario esta bien armado. 
Por lo que leí en la documentación tengo que descargar dos archivos PHP, el Class.phpmailer.php y el SMTP.php y vincularlos de la manera que lo estoy haciendo con un require, ambos archivos están en la misma raíz donde estaría el envio.php que el archivo que escribo abajo. 
Por otro lado no me queda bien en claro que tipo de datos tengo que tener del cliente para que los datos lleguen a su cuenta. 
En este ejemplo estoy haciendo con datos de mi cuenta de hotmail para hacer dichas pruebas.

Por otro lado estoy haciendo un script donde vinculo el archivo PHP por medio de Ajax quería saber si es correctamente armado.

```js
<?php
function envioMail(){

$ecommerce = $_POST["Ecommerce"];
$nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
$telefono = $_POST["Telefono"];
$email = $_POST["Email"];

require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("SMTP.php");
require("Exception.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com"; // A RELLENAR. Aquí pondremos el SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. mail.midominio.com smtp.gmail.com
$mail->Username = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // A RELLENAR. Email de la cuenta de correo. ej.info@midominio.com La cuenta de correo debe ser creada previamente. 
$mail->Password = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aqui pondremos la contraseña de la cuenta de correo
$mail->From = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com";  // A RELLENAR Desde donde enviamos (Para mostrar). Puede ser el mismo que el email creado previamente.
$mail->FromName = "Mariano"; //A RELLENAR Nombre a mostrar del remitente. 
$mail->Subject = "Mensaje de Welivery"; // Este es el titulo del email.
$mail->AddAddress("marianoandres_17@hotmail.com");/*email de CM*/

$body  = 
"
Se ha informado la descarga del siguiente resultado: $codigoAlerta

Muchas gracias

Equipo PfAst
Pfizer
"; 
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Send();

}
if($_POST){
switch($_POST["tarea"]){
case "envio":envioMail();break;
}
}
?>
```

```html
$(function(){ 

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");
  
  function clearInputs(){
    errorMessage.html("");
    validMessage.html("");
  }
  $(".inputValidation").on("click", function(e){
      clearInputs();
  });


  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
    clearInputs();
    var hasError = false;
    var hasvalid = true;
    var exprMail= /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.attr("name") === "email"){
          if( !(exprMail.test($this.val()) ) ) {
            hasError = true;

            $this.addClass("inputError");
            errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, ingrese un email valido.</p>");
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }


        if($this.val() == ""){
          hasError = true;

          $this.addClass("inputError");
          errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
          e.preventDefault();
        }

        if($this.val() != ""){
          $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

        }else{
          return true; 
        }
        
      });      

      errorMessage.slideDown(700);

      if(hasError == false){
          Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
          Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
          Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
          Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
          data2= { 
              ecommerce:Ecommerce,
              nombre:Nombre,
              telefono:Telefono,
              email:Email,
              tarea: "envio"
            };

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"envio.php",
            data: data2,
            success:function(data){
              
              /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
                "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
              );*/

            },
            
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
                "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
              );
              $(".inputValidation").val("");
            } 

          });

      }

  }); //Form .submit
});
```

Answer (score 4):

para darte una mano te dejo las configuraciones que uso en PHPMAILER para armar un mail con informacion obtenida de la base de datos, usando plantillas y envieando el mail con imagenes embebidas:

**ACTUALIZACION:** Si vas a usar un mail de GMAIL hay que entrar a las configuracion de gmail y modificar lo relacionado a aplicaciones mas seguras:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879

- Inicia sesión con tu cuenta de administrador.
- Haz clic en Seguridad > Configuración básica.
- En Aplicaciones poco seguras, selecciona Acceder a los ajustes de las aplicaciones poco seguras.
- En la ventana secundaria, activa la opción Permitir a los usuarios administrar su acceso a las aplicaciones poco seguras.
- Una vez que hayas activado esta opción, los usuarios del grupo o la unidad organizativa a los que se aplique podrán permitir o impedir el acceso de las aplicaciones poco seguras.

**Documentacion de PhpMailer en GitHub:**

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Archivos requeridos

```
require '../core/mail/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

En este ejemplo traigo informacion de la base para ir llenando variables y personalizar el correo

```
$detalleReporte = MvcControllerBug::reporteModel("bugreport bu", 
$_SESSION["idUsuario"]);
$fechaReporte = $detalleReporte[0];
$detalleBug = $detalleReporte[1];
$direccionReporte = $detalleReporte[2];
$mailUsuario = $detalleReporte[3];
$nombreUserMail = $_SESSION['nombre']." ".$_SESSION['apellido'];
$fechaFinal=date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($fechaReporte));
$detalleFinal = "<b><li>Fecha de generacion de reporte: </b> ".$fechaFinal."</li><li> 
<b>Detalle cargado por
el usuario: </b>".$detalleBug."</li><li><b>Pagina desde donde se envio la 
Sugerencia / Bug / Reporte: </b>".$direccionReporte."</li>
<li><b>Mail del usuario: </b>".$mailUsuario."</li>";
$nombreApellido = $_SESSION['nombre']." ".$_SESSION['apellido'];
```

Aca comienza el mail

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('NOMBRE DEL HOST');
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "MAIL DESDE DONDE SALE EL CORREO";
$mail->Password = "CONTRASEÑA DE ESE MAIL";
$mail->setFrom('MAIL DESDE DONDE VA A DECIR QUE SALIO', 'NOMBRE');
$mail->addReplyTo('MAIL A DONDE SE PUEDE RESPONDER', 'NOMBRE');
$mail->addBcc('MAILS OCULTOS A LOS QUE SE VA A ENVIAR TAMBIEN', 'NOMBRE');
$mail->addBcc('MAILS OCULTOS A LOS QUE SE VA A ENVIAR TAMBIEN', 'NOMBRE');
$mail->addBcc('MAILS OCULTOS A LOS QUE SE VA A ENVIAR TAMBIEN', 'NOMBRE');
```

Aca va el mail a quien se lo vas a mandar mas el nombre de esa persona, en este caso tengo variables porque las declare mas arriba:

```
$mail->addAddress($mailUsuario, $nombreUserMail);
```

Podes embeber imagenes en el mail llamandolas de esta formas, vas a necesitar una plantilla de como queres que se vea el mail, unas lineas mas abajo la llamo y te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../core/mail/mail.jpg', '1200_600');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../core/mail/footer.jpg', 'footer');
```

Cuando veas la plantilla avs a ver que las imagenes se declaran aca y en el template se llaman de esta forma:

```
src="cid:1200_600"
```

Titulo del mail, uso las variables que declare arriba para personalizarlo:

```
$mail->Subject = "Reporte ".$_SESSION['nombre']." ".$_SESSION['apellido']."  Nueva Sugerencia";
```

Llamo a la plantilla que arma como se va a ver el mail:

```
$shtml = file_get_contents('../core/mail/template.html');
```

Cuerpo del mail con variables declaradas arriba, fijate que paso por variable $shtml que es la plantilla

Fijate esta linea:
Yo arriba declare una variable $detalleFinal esa tiene adentro lo que va a leer en el cuerpo del mail el usuario, en esta linea especifica lo que hace es ir a la plantilla y buscar el id="mensaje" y a ese elemento le mete el $detalleFinal para que se vea, es como las imagenes, declaras todo aca y dsp lo vas metiendo en la plantilla:

```
$cuerpo = str_replace('<i id="mensaje"></i>',  $detalleFinal, $shtml);
$mail->Body = $cuerpo;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
```

Termino por enviar el mail

```
$mail->send();
```

**PLANTILLA:**

Podes descargar distintos modelos desde esta pagina:

https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Una vez que lo hagas solo borras lo que no te sirve y lo vas amoldando a tu informacion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
            </head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition: 0.3s; width: 40%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                                <img src="cid:1200_600" width="900" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 900px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; margin: auto;" class="g-img">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="padding: 40px 0; text-align: center">
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 30px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                                            <h1 style="margin: 0 0 10px; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; color: #333333; font-weight: normal;">Nuevo Reporte</h1>
                                            <br>
                                            <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: disc;">
                                                <i id="mensaje"></i>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="padding: 40px 0; text-align: center">
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                                <img src="cid:footer" width="900" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 900px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; margin: auto;" class="g-img">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Y el mail llegaria mas o menos asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar un mensaje si el mail salio o no hago lo siguiente:

Para eso uso sweetalert:

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Necesitas Jquery tambien: https://jquery.com/

Te descargas el archivo o usas el CDN:

Ahora valido, si el mail salio muestro un mensaje y si no uno de error.
En este caso en mi codigo tengo una variable que se llama redirecionamiento porque ahi le paso a donde lo voy a mandar una vez que cierre la notificacion el usuario o se cierre sola despues de 1.5 seg.

```
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo '<script>swal("Error al enviar el reporte", 
            "Ocurrio un error durante la generacion del reporte", "error", 
            {closeOnClickOutside: false, closeOnEsc: false, timer: 1500}).then((value) => {
            window.location.replace("'.$redireccionamiento.'");
            });</script>'; 
        } else {
             echo '<script>swal("Mail enviado con exito", 
            "Ya recibimos tu consulta, muchas gracias.", "success", 
            {closeOnClickOutside: false, closeOnEsc: false, timer: 1500}).then((value) => {
            window.location.replace("'.$redireccionamiento.'");
            });</script>'; 
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Juan, ahi estoy mirando veo que es muy distinto a como yo le venia armando

Comment: Hola Juan como estas? tengo una consulta sobre como puedo generar un mensaje de respuesta al usuario cuando completa los campos del form, debajo publique algo que arme pero qe no me esta resultando.

Answer (score 0):

Consulta, estoy queriendo generar que cuando se completen los campos del formulario y se haga el envio el usuario pueda recibir algun tipo de mensaje de que se pondran en contacto con el, el problema es que nose si estoy generano bien el archivo php con la respuesta.

```html
$(function(){ 

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");
  
  function clearInputs(){
    errorMessage.html("");
    validMessage.html("");
  }
  $(".inputValidation").on("click", function(e){
      clearInputs();
  });


  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
    clearInputs();
    var hasError = false;
    var hasvalid = true;
    var exprMail= /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.attr("name") === "email"){
          if( !(exprMail.test($this.val()) ) ) {
            hasError = true;

            $this.addClass("inputError");
            errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, ingrese un email valido.</p>");
            errorMessage.slideDown(700);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }


        if($this.val() == ""){
          hasError = true;

          $this.addClass("inputError");
          errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
          errorMessage.slideDown(700);
          e.preventDefault();
        }

        if($this.val() != ""){
          $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

        }else{
          return true; 
        }
        
      }); //Input
     

  /*
    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);

      if($this.val() == ""){
        hasvalid = false;
        $this.addClass("inputError");
        validMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
        e.preventDefault();
      }if($this.val() != ""){
        $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

      }else{
        return true; 
        }

      }); //Input
    validMessage.slideDown(700);*/

      /*ajax*/
      if(hasError == false){
       $.ajax({
              type: 'POST', 
              url:'envio.php',
              dataType:'json', 
              data: $('#form_step1').serialize(),
             success:function(response){
                console.log("estoy en el ajax");
                console.log(response);
                $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
                  "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
                );
                $(".inputValidation").val("");
                /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
                  "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
                );*/
               
              },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            } 

            });

        }




  }); //Form .submit
});
```

```js
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

if ((isset($_POST['ecommerce']) && $_POST['ecommerce'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['telefono']) && $_POST['telefono']!= "" ) &&
 (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!= "") &&
 (isset($_POST['envio']) && $_POST['envio'] === 'envio')  ){

 
 require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

 
 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio = $_POST['envio'];


 $body  = 
 "
 Datos enviados por el usuario desde el Formulario de contacto: 
 
 $ecommerce
 $nombre
 $telefono
 $email

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= "marianoandres17"; // su contraseña 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->From = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body =$body;

 $address = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // 
 $mail->addAddress($address);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }

 
 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio = $_POST['envio'];


 $body  = 
 "
 En brevedad nos estaremos comunicando.

 Muchas Gracias!

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= ""; // su contraseña 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->From = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Mariano";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Respuesta de Formulario Welivery";
 $mail->Body =$body;

 // $address = $email; // 
 $mail->addAddress($email);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }



} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' =>'No se pudo enviar el email, asegurese que el email exista!!!'));
    die($output);
}
```

Comment: Ahi agregue a mi respuesta original como mostrar un mensaje cuando el mail sale o un error

Comment: Bien Juan, y te hago una ultima consulta, lo que me pusiste lo voy a probar yo de cualquier manera había generado una respuesta desde el sitio, lo que en realidad yo quería saber si se puede realizar una respuesta que le llegue al usuario a su correo? Uno de los campos que tiene que completar es su email saber si a su casilla le puede llegar un correo que diga: En breve nos estaremos comunicando. Yo en el php que adjunte ultimo hice algo pero no me esta funcionado.

Comment: Fijate que en el codigo yo lo hago tengo la variable $mailUsuario = $detalleReporte[3]; que viene de la base de datos vos lo podes hacer con el POST directamente metiendo el valor que te llega adentro de la variable $mailUsuario y dsp en el codigo de PHPMAILER lo metes aca $mail->addReplyTo($mailUsuario, 'NOMBRE'); El nombre del usuario tambien puede venir por variable o le pones algo por defecto, ahora si tenes que mandar un mail a un lugar con algo y dsp otro con otra cosa ahi serian dos funciones una que mande el mail a un lugar y si ese mail salio otro que mande el mensaje al usuario

Comment: Por lo que veo ahi vos pones esto  $mail->From = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Mariano"; y que ese es el mail del usuario, pero esa parte del codigo dice desde donde sale al mail que seria el tuyo, ahora tenes que poner a quien se lo tenes que mandar en el addReplyTo

Comment: Perfecto Juan! voy a probar y te estaré contando.

Comment: Hola Juan como estas, sigo teniendo problemas con el phpmailer, estoy armando el php que adjunto en la respuesta, el problema es que con una cuenta gmail q registre anda y con otras q ya tenia no, los datos no estan entrando.

Comment: Buenas, no estoy con una pc a mano y no me cargan los datos (pesima internet) por si las dudas para empezar fijate que gmail tiene una validacion de seguridad para enviar mails desde aplicaciones de terceros, no me aucerdo ahora como se llama, pero es una opcion que tenes que deshabilitar (y te dice que es inseguro y bla bla) para que gmail permita que el mail salga desde su casilla, tal vez te falta deshabilitar esa opcion de seguridad en gmail.

Comment: Creo q era esto, leelo y fijate: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es-419

Comment: Claro ahi me genere una cuenta nueva para probar y me pasa lo mismo no me deja recibir datos del formulario solamente me anda una que creo un amigo es muy raro todo

Comment: No soy muy bueno en php y no estoy muy mal tanto pense que era algo mas sencillo esto.

Comment: Nada es sencillo, yo programo hace 4 años y todavia me fijo en w3 como se arma el for de php porque no me acuerdo nunca la estructura, pero lo que importa es que aprendas a pensar el problema y la solucion lo demas se encuentra googleando. Proba eso que te pase de deshabilitar la seguridad para que gmail deje salir mails de app no seguras.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

if ((isset($_POST['ecommerce']) && $_POST['ecommerce'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['telefono']) && $_POST['telefono']!= "" ) &&
 (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!= "") &&
 (isset($_POST['envio']) && $_POST['envio'] === 'envio')  ){

 
 require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');


 //MAtest2018.01@gmail   MAtest201801!
 $emailCliente = "xxxx@gmail.com";
 $passwordCliente = "xxxx";
 
 $fromCliente = $emailCliente;


 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio =  $_POST['envio'];
 $address = $email;

 $body  = 
 "
 Datos enviados por el usuario desde el Formulario de contacto: <br/> 
 
 <strong>Ecommerce:</strong> $ecommerce <br/>
 <strong>Nombre y Apellido:</strong> $nombre <br/>
 <strong>Teléfono:</strong> $telefono <br/>
 <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br/>

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= $emailCliente; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= $passwordCliente; // su contraseña 
 $mail->From = $emailCliente; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Welivery";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body = $body;

 $mail->addAddress("electricmarianf@gmail.com", $nombre);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }

 /*
 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio = $_POST['envio'];


 $body  = 
 "
 En brevedad nos estaremos comunicando.

 Muchas Gracias!

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= "heyimariano@gmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= "marianoandres"; // su contraseña 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->From = "heyimariano@gmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Welivery";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body =$body;

 // $address = $email; // 
 $mail->addAddress($email);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }*/



} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' =>'No se pudo enviar el email, asegurese que el email exista!!!'));
    die($output);
}
```