# Envio formato de tabla y datos a correo con php

Tags: php, html

Como podría implementar el diseño de la tabla para que llegue al correo destinatario como se muestra en pantalla de consulta, si tiene  alguna sugerencia o ayuda de cualquier forma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#A4A4A4" style="font-size:15px">
<tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="12" BGCOLOR="#B2BABB"><font size="2.9">REGISTRO DE GANADORES</th>
</tr>
<th width="50" BGCOLOR="#B2BABB"><font size="2">ITEM </font></th>
<th width="55" BGCOLOR="#B2BABB"><font size="2">FECHA </font></th>
<th width="50" BGCOLOR="#B2BABB"><font size="2">OCURRENCIA</th>
<th width="50" BGCOLOR="#B2BABB"><font size="2">USER</th>
</tr>

<?php 
$fechaIni="";
$fechaFin="";
$suma=0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $busca="";
    $busca1="";
    $busca=$_POST['busca'];
    $busca1=$_POST['busca1'];
    $f="";

$mysqli =new mysqli('localhost','','','');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if($busca!="" && $busca1!=""){
    $res= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM datos Where Fecha BETWEEN '$busca' AND '$busca1'");
    $concatenado=''; 
    $cabeza.="Item"."     "."Fecha"."      "."Ocurrencia"."        "."User";

    while($f=$res->fetch_array()){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <?php
    $concatenado .="<strong>".$f['Item']."</string><br>"."   ".$f['Fecha']."   ".$f['ocurrencia']."  ".$f['user']."\n";
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $concatenado .=$f['Item']."   ".$f['Fecha']."   ".$f['ocurrencia']."  ".$f['user']."\n";  
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"> <font size="1"><?php echo $f['Item'] ?></td>
    <td align="center"> <font size="1"><?php echo $f['Fecha'] ?></td>   
    <td align="center"> <font size="1"><?php echo $f['ocurrencia'] ?></td>
    <td align="center"><font size="1"><?php echo $f['user'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }

ini_set('date.timezone','America/Lima');
echo "<p align=right>".date("d/m/Y")."<br>".date("h:i:s");
    }
}
mail('correo@gmail.com','mi titulo',$concatenado);  
?>

<div align="center">
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fijate esta pregunta que hi puse como mandar mails con php mailer usando plantillas para que lleguen al mail destinatario con formatos, estilos e imagenes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214502/consulta-sobre-phpmailer/214518#214518

Comment: Tendrias que usar PHPMailer, en la pagina de [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) tienes informacion necesaria, actualizada y seguro para enviar mails desde el servidor. PHPMailer tiene el objeto `$mail->isHTML(true);` que permite enviar un mail con formato html. Lo que te indica @Juan esta perfecto