# Generar un mensaje automático al usuario al completar los datos en un formulario

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

Estoy realizando pruebas en este [sitio](http://bric.com.ar/ws/) en un Formulario y quisiera generar un mensaje automático al usuario una ves que completo los datos del formulario. 
Como podría hacerlo? adjunto el js y el php implementado.

```js
$(function(){ 

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");
  
  function clearInputs(){
    errorMessage.html("");
    validMessage.html("");
  }
  $(".inputValidation").on("click", function(e){
      clearInputs();
  });


  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
    clearInputs();
    var hasError = false;
    var hasvalid = true;
    var exprMail= /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.attr("name") === "email"){
          if( !(exprMail.test($this.val()) ) ) {
            hasError = true;

            $this.addClass("inputError");
            errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, ingrese un email valido.</p>");
            errorMessage.slideDown(700);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }


        if($this.val() == ""){
          hasError = true;

          $this.addClass("inputError");
          errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
          errorMessage.slideDown(700);
          e.preventDefault();
        }

        if($this.val() != ""){
          $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

        }else{
          return true; 
        }
        
      }); //Input

      if(hasError == false){
       $.ajax({
              type: 'POST', 
              url:'envio.php',
              dataType:'json', 
              data: $('#form_step1').serialize(),
             success:function(response){
                console.log("estoy en el ajax");
                console.log(response);
                $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
                  "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
                );
                $(".inputValidation").val("");
                /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
                  "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
                );*/
               
              },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            } 

            });

        }




  }); //Form .submit
});
```

```html
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

if (  (isset($_POST['ecommerce']) && $_POST['ecommerce'] != "") &&
  (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "") &&
  (isset($_POST['telefono']) && $_POST['telefono']!= "" ) &&
  (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!= "") &&
  (isset($_POST['envio']) && $_POST['envio'] === 'envio')  ){

 
 require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

 
 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio = $_POST['envio'];


 $body  = 
 "
 Se ha informado la descarga del siguiente resultado: $nombre

 Muchas gracias

 Equipo PfAst
 Pfizer
 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= "marianoandres@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= ""; // su contraseña 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->From = "marianoandres@hotmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Mariano";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body =$body;

 $address = "marianoandres@hotmail.com"; // 
 $mail->addAddress($address);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Gracias el email se a enviado'));
     die($output);
 }

} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' =>'No se pudo enviar el email, asegurese que el email exista!!!'));
    die($output);
}
```

Comment: Al menos la forma de hacerlo: usando Ajax para llamar el código de envío de mensaje desde el servidor, es correcto. ¿Tienes algún problema en concreto? ¿Da algún error?

Comment: No no como error no tengo nada, solo queria saber si existe alguna forma de poder hacer eso que comente. Si tiene mucha complejidad.

Comment: La  mejor forma de hacerlo es, una vez comprobado que el formulario está completo (existen varios métodos para eso), enviar una petición Ajax al servidor para que envíe el correo. En la petición puedes incluir datos como el email, el nombre de la persona, etc. En el servidor compruebas que todo se desarrolló con normalidad y devuelves un mensaje al cliente de que todo ha ido bien o, si hubo algún error, le informas de que algo salió mal.

Comment: Bien, por casualidad tendrias algun ejemplo para pasarme para ver como hacerlo?

Comment: Lamentablemente no tengo ejemplo sobre esto, no sé si aquí encuentres alguno, es cuestión de buscar, aquí o en otros sitios. La cuestión es muy simple: *Paso 1*: Validar/verificar que el formulario se llenó correctamente; *Paso 2*: Si se verifica que el formulario está correctamente cumplimentando, lanzar la petición Ajax que envía el mensaje. ¿Cómo hacer el *Paso 1*? Hay mil formas de hacerlo, puedes validarlo tú mismo o usar algún plugin de validación de formularios, eso debes decidirlo tú. ¿Cómo hacer el *Paso 2*? Como lo estás haciendo, vía Ajax.

Comment: Oka gracias voy la información, te consultaba porque soy medio nuevo con esto y en parte lo que fui armando fue por unos tutoriales que fui viendo pero no encontré sobre eso.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano estuve publicando una cosas aca queria saber si podras darme una mano. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214502/consulta-sobre-phpmailer/214518#214518