# Mandar a distintos destinatarios Php Mailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo un generado de pedido, y cuando este es correcto manda un mail al cliente con agradecimientos y la factura que corresponde. Pero necesitaría que a la vez mande un mail a otra dirección que seria la administración para que sepan que han recibido un pedido nuevo. Claro tiene que ir con un contenido distinto el mensaje.

Esto es como lo tengo ahora:

```
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
//$html = str_replace("�", "&Aacute;", $html);

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

ini_set("memory_limit","64M");
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("facturas/".$facturaid.".pdf", $pdf);
/* ENVIO DE PDF POR CORREO ELECTRÓNICO */
include "plantillaEmail/templatePedido.php";
include "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
include "PHPMailer/class.smtp.php";

$email_user = "usuario@mail.com";
$email_password = "pass";
$the_subject = "Factura " . $facturaid;
$address_to = $usuariosArray['Username'];
$from_name = "Depildiodo";
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
// ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail -------------------------------
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "mail.depildiodo.com"; // GMail
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject;
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
$phpmailer->AddAttachment("facturas/".$facturaid.".pdf",
                     $facturaid.".pdf");
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();
$_SESSION['carrito']= array();
if($redireccion != ""){
  header('Location: '.$redireccion, true, 301);
}else {
header('Location: index.php', true, 301);
}
```

Alguna sugerencia por favor?

Comment: No entendi bien la consulta, te dejo por si te sirve una respuesta que deje en otro post donde puse un ejemplo completo de mail con correos ocultos y formato https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214518/3092 por si te sirve

Comment: Hola @Juan se me hace costoso entender lo que me mandas, es la primera vez que utilizo phpMailer. Lo que quiero hacer es que además de enviar el mail que estoy enviando ahora con una factura, es que también lo pueda enviar a otro mail pero esta vez diciendo ejpl "Hemos recibido un nuevo pedido".

Comment: Hace dos funciones, una que mande el mail a uno con su respectivo texto y otra que mande a otro y al momento de ejecutarlo las llamas a las dos. Lo que te pase ahi es un ejemplo completo de un mail destinado a una sola o a un grupo de personas con el mismo contenido donde podes poner copias ocultas con $mail->addBcc('MAILS OCULTOS A LOS QUE SE VA A ENVIAR TAMBIEN', 'NOMBRE'); en una sola funcion nunca hice que mande dos mails distintos.

Comment: yo implementaria  `clearAllRecipients( )`

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que buscar enviar correos individuales pero con el mismo contenido lo ideal seria utilizar: [clearAllRecipients( )](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_clearAllRecipients)

> clearAllRecipients( )
> Clear all recipient types.
> public clearAllRecipients() : mixed

Ejemplo de la implementacion:

```
<?php
// Tu código previo aquí...

// Generación del PDF y otras operaciones...

// Configuración del correo para el cliente
$address_to = $usuariosArray['Username'];
$the_subject = "Factura " . $facturaid;
$from_name = "Depildiodo";
$body = "Aquí puedes agregar el contenido personalizado del correo para el cliente.";

$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password;
$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "mail.depildiodo.com";
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP();
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username, $from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to);
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject;
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
$phpmailer->AddAttachment("facturas/".$facturaid.".pdf", $facturaid.".pdf");
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();

// Configuración del correo para la administración
$admin_email = "admin@mail.com"; // Cambia esto a la dirección de administración
$admin_subject = "Nuevo pedido recibido";
$admin_body = "Aquí puedes agregar el contenido personalizado del correo para la administración.";

$phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients(); // Limpia los destinatarios anteriores
$phpmailer->AddAddress($admin_email);
$phpmailer->Subject = $admin_subject;
$phpmailer->Body = $admin_body;
$phpmailer->Send();

$_SESSION['carrito'] = array();

if ($redireccion != "") {
    header('Location: '.$redireccion, true, 301);
} else {
    header('Location: index.php', true, 301);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes encapsular todo como una función que tenga los parámetros necesarios (el destinatario) y ya después invocarla las veces que lo ocupes con diferentes parámetros.

Se me ocurre algo de rápido de esta manera.

```
function enviarCorreo($correo, $contenido){
      //codigo de enviar correo 
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Noel Camacho gracias por tu respuesta, no se como hacer lo que me comentas, me puedes guiar un poco más por favor, es la primera vez que utilizo phpMailer

Answer (score -1):

No se compliquen tanto la vida amigos, existen tantas librerias y tantas api's

[Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/)

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Mailjet\Resources;
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client(getenv('MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC'), getenv('MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE'),true,['version' => 'v3.1']);
$body = [
    'Messages' => [
        [
            'From' => [
                'Email' => "pilot@mailjet.com",
                'Name' => "Mailjet Pilot"
            ],
            'To' => [
                [
                    'Email' => "passenger1@mailjet.com",
                    'Name' => "passenger 1"
                ],
                [
                    'Email' => "passenger2@mailjet.com",
                    'Name' => "passenger 2"
                ]
            ],
            'Cc' => [
                [
                    'Email' => "copilot@mailjet.com",
                    'Name' => "Copilot"
                ]
            ],
            'Bcc' => [
                [
                    'Email' => "air-traffic-control@mailjet.com",
                    'Name' => "Air traffic control"
                ]
            ],
            'Subject' => "Your email flight plan!",
            'TextPart' => "Dear passenger 1, welcome to Mailjet! May the delivery force be with you!",
            'HTMLPart' => "<h3>Dear passenger 1, welcome to <a href=\"https://www.mailjet.com/\">Mailjet</a>!</h3><br />May the delivery force be with you!"
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $body]);
$response->success() && var_dump($response->getData());
```